# How do you create an animated mask for an image to show underlying video for v2.82a?

Tags: animation, masking, timeline, movie-clip-editor

**EDIT**

I'm using Blender's video editor to overlay an image on top of my video footage. The problem is, I need to mask (make transparent) certain parts of the image that are currently blocking part of the video at certain frames. I am able to create a single frame mask and apply it to an adjustment layer that works as exactly as intended by showing the underlying video. I was able to create an animated mask in the movie editor, but when I apply it to the adjustment layer the mask doesn't work at all. I compared the strip settings of both the single frame and animated masks and they are identical, both using Alpha Over as a blend mode. I followed [**this video tutorial**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_06cWLUZ_Bg) (times 7:22 - 9:22) but the animated mask is still not masking at all. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Here's a video that goes over that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXsrkg31VRI

Comment: Thanks, but I already watched that video. The guy is using preexisting mask files. He doesn't show how to do it in Blender.

Comment: Create a grayscale image. Following the settings he used, Black = transparent, white = opaque. Paint black where you want the masked video to be transparent, white where you want it to show, and gray if you want something in between. Some of the settings will be in different places in 2.8, but the overall process is the same

Comment: That's the part I don't know how to do is "paint" the mask. Do you know where I can do this in Blender's video editor?

Comment: You'll have to create a new image texture that is then used as the mask. You can do so using Blender's texture editor or external software.

Comment: I would have to do it in external software since I'm not familiar with Blender's texture node editor. Do you know how to export the mask from Blender once I create it?

Comment: Do you mean how to import the mask into Blender? The masks are just image files, so you import them like any other texture. You can then put them into the video editor, and set them to act as a mask in a similar manner to the linked video above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107225/discussion-between-gig6-and-stphnl329).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So my problem was that I wasn't aware that the mask had a start frame and end frame setting (in red). By default it was set to start at frame 1 and end at frame 100. I thought because I created the mask at frame 674 to frame 800 (in purple) that it would automatically be applied to those frames. As I scrubbed the video I could see the mask animate at the proper frames (from 674 to 800) so I thought I had done everything correctly. I upvoted susu's answer because that IS the correct way to apply a mask, which is exactly what I was doing, I just didn't have it set to the proper frames.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the movie clip editor (not the sequencer) you can create and animate masks.

[image]

In the VSE select the strip you want to overlay, add a "mask" strip modifier and select the mask you want to use. Then set the strip to use "alpha over" blend mode in the Adjust->Compositng settings for the strip.

The top strip will be overlayed on the bottom strip using the mask as alpha channel.

[image]

There is no need to create black and white images to be used as masks. The mask tools for blender are quite sophisticated.