# How to use masks on video so that some elements appear in the foreground and others in the back in VSE

Tags: video-sequence-editor, image, video, masking, layers

I have two people in my video - one in the **foreground** and the other in the **background**. I want to **place an image** of a cage over **the person in the background** of the video, but the issue I have is the person in the foreground would then be covered with the image also. How do I place this image behind the person in the foreground to make the scene realistic?
(I'm using the *video editor* workspace).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175980/92768

Comment: I'll check it out. Thank you.

Comment: Read the following post: [how to attach text to a tracked point on video clip](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38549/how-would-i-attach-text-to-a-tracked-point-on-video-clip)