# How to make something pass behind an actor and be not visible. (Just the part behind the actor)

Tags: animation, transparency, movie-clip-editor

[image]I want to make the wings pass behind the actor during the animation, how can I do it? I need to make the wings pass behind the actor and when they are behind, the part behind him need to be not visible. I don't know if i can use an alpha on the holdout material or if there is an other way. thanks

Comment: You'd have to create a mask for your actor: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/175980/31447

Comment: Did you succeed with this one?